# How to fix unity humanoid animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I ran into a problem while preparing a personal project.By the way, I am using a translator, so please understand. Is there a way to fix humanoid animations imported Unity assets? Or I wonder if it is possible to unlock read-only mode. I would be grateful if someone could help me with this issue.

To fix this, I tried changing the humanoid type to generic, but it failed.

Comment: you need to be more clear. What do you mean "fix", do you have a humanoid model/animation and it doesn't work? If not, what's wrong with it exactly?

Comment: If you're working with [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com) animations then you can alleviate the read-only restriction by duplicating the animation clip inside the downloaded asset, thus separating it from the Mixamo model.